# Go to definition for ES6 imports if index.js is omitted

Tags: visual-studio-code

In ES6 (like node), importing a module like this

`import something from 'something';`

Is the same as

`import something from 'something/index';`

However, vscode appears incapable of performing "Go To Definition" if importing modules using the first method. If I append `index`, "Go To Definition" works. Is there a way to modify `jsconfig.json` to have vscode check the `index` file by default?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today. Opened a bug with vscode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24715

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[I asked this question on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24715) and received this response from Matt Bierner (Microsoft).

> Does your project have a jsconfig.json? Can you make sure it contains the setting:
>
> `{
>     "compilerOptions": {
>       "module": "commonjs"
>     }
>   }`

Adding the above configuration to my [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) seems to have fixed the issue even though I'm using ES6 `import` and `export` syntax.

However this shouldn't be an issue since,

> In a jsconfig, the module option only changes how paths are resolved

[You can read more about the `module` setting here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_down-level-compilation-with-typescript-compiler)

Comment: Unfortunately, this setting doesn't work for me. It seems this issue is somehow/somewhat, and not always, related to the 'baseUrl' setting of jssconfig.json. I've seen quite a few fixes and regressions, as back as summer 2016....

Comment: @Vassilis - if it helps, my `baseUrl` is set to: `"baseUrl": ".",` which I think is default, but I needed it to set up some values for `paths`

Comment: This seems to have fixed it for me. I did have a jsconfig.json file but I had module: "es6" instead of "commonjs" (not sure why "es6" didn't work the same way). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is another solution ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16320#issuecomment-380761115)).
Include the following in your jsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
},
```

Changing `"module": "es6"` to `"module": "commonjs"` worked for me too, but I prefer to keep `module` set to `es6`.